# calc formula interpretation?

Tags: calc

Reading this [twitter](https://twitter.com/ZonePhysics/status/1113620052857761797?s=19) and applying Pemdas I believe that the answer should be 9, but applying this formula in emacs-calc yields 1:

```
'6/2(1+2)  ==>
alg' 6 / 2 * (2 + 1)
 1
```

Hard to believe I'm wrong, but even harder to believe emacs-calc is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[(calc) Basic Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Basic-Arithmetic.html):

> When combining multiplication and division in an algebraic formula,
>   it is good style to use parentheses to distinguish between possible
>   interpretations; the expression `a/b*c` should be written `(a/b)*c` or
>   `a/(b*c)`, as appropriate.  Without the parentheses, Calc will
>   interpret `a/b*c` as `a/(b*c)`, since in algebraic entry Calc gives
>   division a lower precedence than multiplication.  (This is not
>   standard across all computer languages, and Calc may change the
>   precedence depending on the language mode being used.  See [(calc) Language Modes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Language-Modes.html).)  This default ordering can be changed by setting the
>   customizable variable `calc-multiplication-has-precedence` to `nil`
>   (see [(calc) Customizing Calc](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/calc/Customizing-Calc.html)); this will give multiplication and division
>   equal precedences. Note that Calc’s default choice of precedence
>   allows `a b / c d` to be used as a shortcut for
>
> ```
>      a b
>      ---.
>      c d
> ```